# How to change getRealPath("/") path from .metadata to WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, relative-path, absolute-path

I am uploading image files from application, now I want to save them in WEB-INF, but eclipse is saving it in .metadata folder *.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps*.

Please let me know who can I get the path to WEB-INF3

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,HttpServletRequest request) {//httservlet- aswe need to use that toget thesessionpath
    productDao.addProduct(product);
    /////add image
    MultipartFile productImage= product.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory= request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); //C:\Users\Avinash Kharche\ECommerce_Spring_Neon\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\emusicStore\
    path =Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId()+".png");

    //path =Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Avinash Kharche\\ECommerce_Spring_Neon\\emusicStore\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId()+".png");


    if(productImage!=null && !productImage.isEmpty()){
        try{
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed",e);

        }
    }
    /////
    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";

}
```

I dont want to use commented **path**

(//path =Paths.get("C:\Users\Avinash Kharche\ECommerce_Spring_Neon\emusicStore\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\images\" + product.getProductId()+".png");)

Please let me know any solution. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, HttpServletRequest request) {
    productDao.addProduct(product);

    MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF/resources/images/" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

    if (productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed", e);
        }
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
}
```

Change path from:

```
path =Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId()+".png");
```

To

```
path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF/resources/images/" + product.getProductId() + ".png");
```

Make sure you do the same for edit and delete functions. I had the same problem. With your version, it worked on windows but on Mac, I had to change the path as shown above